# How to trigger an action with select_tag without using the deprecated remote_function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application that lists events. I want the user to be able to filter the events by category. In order to do this, I want to have a select box within which a user can select a category. When the user selects a category, I want an action to be triggered which will use JavaScript to list events from just that category. All Stack Overflow posts explaining how to do this use `remote_function`, which has apparently been discontinued. Right now, I have the code

```
select_tag "category",
    options_for_select(['Social', 'Academic','Sports and Recreation', 'Arts', 'Religious'])
```

How can I trigger an action with the `select_tag` when an option from the dropdown box is changed/selected? I'm guessing I may have to use the `:onchange`option, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stick this in the view, after the select tag:

```
<script>
  $('#your_select_tag_id').on('change', function() {
    $.post({
      url: '/your/form/action',
      data: $('#your_form_id').serialize()
    }).success(function(data)) {
      console.log('this is what I got back: ' + data);
    };
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`select_tag` have an `options` hash (last parameter) in which you can add any HTML attributes for the select.

For more information, please take a look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

To add an `onchange` attribute, please take a look at below example:

```
select_tag "category", options_for_select(['Social', 'Academic','Sports and Recreation', 'Arts', 'Religious']), :onchange => 'your_handler_function()'
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `options`-hash parameter can be used for:

```
select_tag "category",
  options_for_select(['Social', 'Academic','Sports and Recreation', 'Arts', 'Religious']), :onchange => 'yourJSFunction()'
```